# How to show $x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 - (x_3y_3 + x_4y_4) > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have the following information. All are labels/variables.

$x_1 < x_3 < x_4 < x_2$

$y_1 < y_3 < y_4 < y_2$

$x_1 + x_2 = x_3 + x_4$

$x_1 + a = x_3$

$x_2 - a = x_4$

- a > 0
- all x and y values are postive

Is there any possibility for me to show that
$x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 - (x_3y_3 + x_4y_4) > 0$ ?

What I've so far is

$x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 - (x_3y_3 + x_4y_4)$

$x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 - ((x_1 + a)y_3 + (x_2 - a)y_4)$

$x_2(y_2 - y_4) + a(y_4 - y_3) - x_1(y_3 - y_1)$

In the above statement, the first 2 parts are positive. But I'm stuck to show that the difference between the first 2 parts and the third part is positive

Comment: What do "x1" "y1" etc. mean? Does it mean $x^1$?

Comment: yeah those are just label names  :)

Comment: are  x1,x2,x3,x4 4 variables or one variable raised to powers. question by puffy confused me

Comment: @MilanStojanovic those are just variables/labels

Comment: $x1$ is $x_1$ and so on, yes? Are all $x$ and $y$ positive?

Comment: @user376343 yes and yes :) But I don't know how to type that way :D

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne wait a moment, I am editing your question.

Comment: @user376343 oops sorry. I already did. Thanks :)

Comment: just a quick though. I think that the assumption $x_{1} + x_{2} = x_{3} + x_{4}$ and then $x_{1} + a = x_{3}$ with $x_{2} - a = x_{4}$ are reduntdant.
Summing up $x_{1} + a = x_{3}$ and $x_{2} - a = x_{4}$ gives you exactly $x_{1} + x_{2} = x_{3} + x_{4}$ :)

Comment: @mortal yeah agree :)

Comment: P/S: if it was $y_{1} + y_{2} = y_{3} + y_{4}$, for example, then I think I know how to do it :)
my impression that you have too many info for $x$ but too less info for $y$.

Comment: y is a function of x :) and it is strictly increasing

Comment: did you mean $y_{1} = y_{1} \left( x_{1} \right)$ and so on...?

Comment: hmm I mean y depend on x. So it is like f:x -> y

Answer (score 2):

The last expression can be written as
$$x_2(y_2−y_4)+a(y_4−y_3)+x_1(y_3−y_1)$$
Here all the terms are positive, hence the inequality follows.

Hope it is helpful:)

Comment: I think I made a mistake in the last statement. I corrected it now in the question. It should be x1(y1−y3). But since y1 -y3 < 0 we can't say the full statement is greater than 0.Sorry for the inconvenience